# Dropbox authorization is not working in Explorer in Windows 7 running under VMWare

Tags: oauth, dropbox, vmware, explorer

Good day to all!

I am trying to authorize in Explorer 11 on dropbox with redirection to http://localhost with such url https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=#client_id_here#&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=token . After authorization with Google dropbox redirects me to page http://localhost/#access_token=#token_here#&token_type=bearer&uid=#uid_here#&account_id=#account_id_here#

But when I do this in VMWare (running in Ubuntu) - Windows 7 - Explorer 11, I am redirecting to https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize_submit and receiving page with "This page can't be displayed • Make sure the web address https://www.dropbox.com is correct.".

In developer tools I see that browser was trying to open url, but then aborted it. When I do this in VMWare - Windows 7 - Chrome everything works fine. And it is also fine when I try this in Windows 7 + Explorer running not under VMWare. So problem is only in VMWare + Explorer.

I've tried to turn off firewall, to clean cache, history and cookies, to downgrade Explorer to 10 and nothing helped.

Comment: Can you check if your server at http://localhost/ is running and accessible to Internet Explorer in the VM displaying the issue?

Comment: I am not running web server. I am trying to intercept redirect to localhost and then extract token from url

Comment: Difference with Chrome and Explorer is that in Chrome I get error while opening url to localhost with token and in Explorer I get error while opening https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize_submit . And with the same actions in Explorer not under VMWare I also get error on localhost with token in url

Comment: If you're not actually running your own server, meaning there's nothing at http://localhost, you probably shouldn't rely on that, as different browsers may handle this differently. You can instead use the redirect receiver page Dropbox offers: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver

Comment: Problem is that the same browser in the same windows works different when windows is running under vmware or not. And not only the same browser. I've tried 10 and 11 Explorer and both of them work correctly when not under VMWare and both of them don't work correctly under VMWare

Comment: I can't speak to differences in browsers/VMs, but I definitely recommend using https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver instead.